Reload Flutter navigator state to the first screen
I would like to reload navigator state to the first screen based on the if condition of department change. My code is given below:
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    AuthenticationNotifier authenticationNotifier =
        Provider.of<AuthenticationNotifier>(context, listen: true);
    UserAppDepartmentModel? currentDepartment =
        authenticationNotifier.getSelectedUserAppDepartment();

    // Check if the Department has changed
    if (currentDepartment != previousDepartment) {
      setState(() {
        cSelectedUserAppDepartment = currentDepartment;
        previousDepartment = currentDepartment; // Update previous value
      });
    }
  }```

please let me know how to do it. 


It can be solved using NavigatorKey. As follow:
 void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    AuthenticationNotifier authenticationNotifier =
        Provider.of<AuthenticationNotifier>(context, listen: true);
    UserAppDepartmentModel? currentDepartment =
        authenticationNotifier.getSelectedUserAppDepartment();

    // Check if the Department has changed
    if (currentDepartment != previousDepartment) {
      setState(() {
        cSelectedUserAppDepartment = currentDepartment;
        previousDepartment = currentDepartment; // Update previous value
        resetNavigators();
      });
    }
  }

  void resetNavigators() {
    YourNavigatorKey.currentState?.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
   
  }

